# Impossible to interrupt thread if its actually computing?

Tags: java, multithreading, concurrency

Given this code...

```
public class SimpleTest {

  @Test
  public void testCompletableFuture() throws Exception {
    Thread thread = new Thread(SimpleTest::longOperation);
    thread.start();

    bearSleep(1);

    thread.interrupt();

    bearSleep(5);
  }

  public static void longOperation(){
    System.out.println("started");
    try {

      boolean b = true;
      while (true) {
        b = !b;
      }

    }catch (Exception e){
      System.out.println("exception happened hurray!");
    }
    System.out.println("completed");
  }

  private static void bearSleep(long seconds){
    try {
      TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(seconds);
    } catch (InterruptedException e) {}
  }
}
```

Imagine that instead of this `while(true)` you have something that does not throw interrupted execution (for example, a recursive function that actually calculates something).

How do you kill this thing? And why is it not dying?

Note if I don't put `Exception` type there and use `InterruptedException` it won't even compile, saying that `"interrupted exception will never be thrown"` which I don't understand why. Maybe I want to interrupt it manually...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I assume you are referring to this segment of code:

```
try {
    boolean b = true;
    while (true) {
        b = !b;
    }
} catch(Exception e) {
    System.out.println("exception happened hurray!");
}
```

The reason you cannot catch an `InterruptedException` here is because there is nothing inside of that block that can throw an `InterruptedException`. `interrupt()` itself will not break the thread out of the loop, instead, it essentially sends a signal to the thread to tell it to stop what it's doing and do something else. If you want `interrupt()` to break the loop, try this:

```
boolean b = true;
while (true) {
    b = !b;
    // Check if we got interrupted.
    if(Thread.interrupted()) {
        break; // Break out of the loop.
    }
}
```

Now the thread will check if it got interrupted, and break out of the loop once it has. No `try-catch` necessary.

Comment: Please remember that with [Thread.interrupted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted%28%29) *The interrupted status of the thread is cleared by this method.*

Comment: That's true. If you want to preserve the status of the `interrupted` flag, the instance method [Thread.isInterrupted()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted%28%29) should be used instead.

Answer (score 2):

[`Thread#interrupt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupt--) is more or less implemented with a flag. If the thread is blocked on some actions, ex: IO or synchronization primitives (see Javadoc), the thread is unblocked and an `InterruptedException`, is thrown in that thread. Otherwise, a simple status flag is set indicating that the thread was interrupted.

Your code needs to check for that status with [`Thread#interrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#interrupted--) or [`Thread#isInterrupted()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Thread.html#isInterrupted--) (or handle the `InterruptedException`).

Note that checking for the status with the `static` method clears the status.

Comment: @Vach `InterruptedException` is a checked exception. The compiler knows when it can and cannot be thrown. In your code, nothing can ever throw it so there's no way you could catch it.

Comment: @Vach Yes, check for the flag at appropriate points in the execution and take an appropriate action.

Comment: thanks, i tought i know what concurrency is, but apparently i have a long way to go :D

Comment: @Vach [Here's](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/interrupt.html) some official documentation about how to handle interrupts.